# PrimeFaces DataTable Enum filtering

Tags: jsf-2, enums, datatable, primefaces, filtering

I am using PF 3.4 and trying to filter a column which has enum value. I am using jsf 2.0's enum converter. But filtering does not work for me here is the sample code :

```
<p:dataTable id="projeTeklifiListesiDataTable"
                value="#{controller.model.projeTeklifiListesi}"
                var="proje" paginator="true" rowKey="#{proje.id}"
                rows="50"
                selection="#{controller.model.secilenProjeTeklifi}"
                selectionMode="single" styleClass="defaultList">


                <p:column headerText="#{etiket['pfdy_hzrl_vt013']}" 
                              filterBy="#{projeTeklifi.projeTeklifiDurumu}"
                              filterOptions="#{controller.model.projeTeklifiDurumuListesi}" 
                    sortBy="#{projeTeklifi.projeTeklifiDurumu.toString()}">  
                       #{proje.projeTeklifiDurumu.toString()}  
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="#{etiket['pfdy_dkd_vt010']}" filterBy="#{projeTeklifi.basariDurumu}"
                    filterOptions="#{controller.model.basariDurumuListesi}"
                    sortBy="#{projeTeklifi.basariDurumu.toString()}">  
                       #{proje.basariDurumu.toString()}  
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

this are the lists for the filter options

```
public SelectItem[] getProjeTeklifiDurumuListesi()
{
    final ProjeTeklifiDurumu[] durumListesi = ProjeTeklifiDurumu.values();
    final SelectItem[] projeTeklifiDurumListesi = new SelectItem[durumListesi.length+1];
    projeTeklifiDurumListesi[0] = new SelectItem("", "Seçiniz");
    for(int i =0;i<durumListesi.length;i++)
    {
        final SelectItem select = new SelectItem(ProjeTeklifiDurumu.valueOf(durumListesi[i].name()),durumListesi[i].toString());
        projeTeklifiDurumListesi[i+1]=select;
    }
    return projeTeklifiDurumListesi;
}

public SelectItem[]  getBasariDurumuListesi()
{
    final BasariDurumu[] durumListesi = BasariDurumu.values();
    final SelectItem[] projeTeklifiDurumListesi = new SelectItem[durumListesi.length+1];
    projeTeklifiDurumListesi[0] = new SelectItem("", "Seçiniz");
    for(int i =0;i<durumListesi.length;i++)
    {
        final SelectItem select = new SelectItem(durumListesi[i],durumListesi[i].toString());
        projeTeklifiDurumListesi[i+1]=select;
    }
    return projeTeklifiDurumListesi;
}
```

I have tried with different value bindings for SelectedItem class bind the enum itself, bind the name of the enum, called toString() method but it does not filter. I can see that my value binding of the filter option is posted correctly but does not filters the data.

Any clue would be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataHelper

```
void decodeFilters(FacesContext context, DataTable table) {
  ...

  String columnValue = String.valueOf(column.getValueExpression("filterBy").getValue(context.getELContext()));
  ...
}
```

They are decoding the value as is, so no converter will be used i think.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i debugged it and see the problem in xhtml there is a space at the beginning of the value field so it never matches the filter.